# Best word for "Complete Interpersonal Transparency"

Tags: word-choice

Once upon a time a friend used a word meaning:

> An approach, attitude, or expectation of complete openness or transparency in an interaction or relationship.

If I remember correctly, it seemed to carry positive connotations, including simplified communication, schematic consistency, etc. I enjoy this logos, but can never find the word to clearly represent it.

> No, I wasn't surprised when the pop-media reported his tryst. We
>   practice **_______**.

p.s. *forthright* was suggested, but is a little off-target in that it speaks more to how *direct* someone is, than to how *revealing*.

Comment: *Forthrightness* should work

Comment: +1, kolossus. I think forthright is generally associated with conveying a single concept, and forthrightness then is a propensity to behave this way when individual topics arise.

The word (if I recall correctly) I'm searching for was a more proactive term. An approach that included conveying information in the absence of specific precursors.

Comment: Not really (IMO anyway). It describes a more encompassing, general quality, much like saying a person is *ingenuous* (antonym of *disingenuous*). I can describe a friend to another friend as being forthright, without any context

Comment: What I'm trying to say, is that M-W says "directly forward, without hesitation". Also, "free from ambiguity or evasiveness : going straight to the point". This tends to imply there is a point present that might be evaded, but instead the person is "forthright".

The word I seek is a specifically pre-emptive relationship strategy.

"No, I wasn't surprised when the pop-media reported his tryst. We practice ______."

As you can see, forthrightness does not work here. It does not preclude information from being withheld, if a topic never arises.

Comment: Reminds me of a Russian term - *glasnost.* [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasnost]

Comment: Is it _candour_ (or candor)?

Comment: I like candor very much for this purpose. It isn't the word I was trying to recall, but it's suitable. Thank you.

Comment: Regarding having the question on hold, I'm not sure how to increase the clarity. From the comments in one suggested answer, I can see that the sample sentence identifies the unique qualities of this word I'm searching for. I'm also fairly confident there is a word meaning transparency, with the nuances I described, that fits this particular role in a sentence. I obviously wish I could remember it, as evidence that it exists. If it helps, I suspect my friend was referring to a common topic discussed by those in a polyamorous community. I didn't get the sense that the word was lingo, though.

Answer (score 3):

Eu.. *honesty*?

(Although it wouldn't completely fit in your blank)

Comment: Thank you for recognizing that it doesn't quite fill the blank. The main reason is honesty is somewhat of a passive activity, relative to what I'm looking for. Yes, I understand that lies of omission can easily still be considered lies. That isn't the distinction I'm trying to make.

Comment: _Practicing_ honesty forces the meaning to shift towards a more active state, but you don't want a word whose meaning has to be altered by another: you want the real deal :)

Answer (score 1):

**Transparency** cannot be otherwise than complete and between persons or parties.

That said, this sense and usage of transparency has gained widespread application and has been well-defined in both management and sociology.

See the excellent piece appearing on Wikipedia:
[Transparency (behavior)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_%28behavior%29)

> … implies openness, communication, and accountability. Transparency is operating in such a way that it is easy for others to see what actions are performed. It has been defined simply as "the perceived quality of intentionally shared information from a sender".[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_%28behavior%29)

Therefore, *transparency* it is.

Comment: +1 for the clarification of the original word. You are right, transparency would work quite well, if it filled the role I was looking for. The implications the word I was seeking carried, the fact that it is an approach or practice aligned with one's values, makes it much more suitable for brevity in communicating this idea, which is why I was looking for it. At this point, following the "keep an open mind" forum rule, I used "transparency" throughout the document, as you suggested, but accepting as an answer the word offered in the initial question removes any future value from this post.

Comment: Shannon, true, I was only reasserting your own idea of using 'transparency,' so the credit rightly belongs to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You might use "openness" or "honesty" as less legalistic alternatives to "transparency".  You might also consider rephrasing to use an adjective instead of a noun:

> We are completely open with one another.